# Laravel 5.2 form validation request not working properly

Tags: php, validation, laravel, request

When I hit submit button nothing happens its just refreshing the page.

Here's my code:

**app/Http/routes.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('profile/edit', 'UserController@editProfile');
    Route::post('update_name', 'UserController@updateName');
});
```

**app/Http/Request/UpdateNameRequest.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UpdateNameRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return Auth::check();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'first_name' => 'required|min:2|alpha',
            'last_name' => 'required|min:2|alpha',
        ];
    }
}
```

**app/Http/Controllers/UserController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function editProfile() {
        if (Auth::user()->role_id === 3) {
            return view('profile.crew.edit');          
        }
    }

    public function updateName(Requests\UpdateNameRequest $request) {
        return dd($request->all());
    }
}
```

**and here's the html form**

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'update_name')) !!}
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('first_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" value="{{ old('first_name') }}" placeholder="{{ Auth::user()->first_name }}">

    @if ($errors->has('first_name'))
        <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('first_name') }}</strong>
        </span>
    @endif
</div>
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('last_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" value="{{ old('last_name') }}" placeholder="{{ Auth::user()->last_name }}">

    @if ($errors->has('last_name'))
        <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('last_name') }}</strong>
        </span>
    @endif
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update name</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**for reference heres the form output**

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/update_name" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="VViupfPaPCQCk5aeUdc27Pt2Z8J7Hx1Y2khC0IY9">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" value="" placeholder="Hans">

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" value="" placeholder="Padberg">

    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update name</button>
</form>
```

**here's my output in php artisan route:list**

```
+--------+----------+-------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                     | Name | Action                                                          | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+-------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                       |      | Closure                                                         | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | home                    |      | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                       | web,web,auth |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                   |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm          | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | login                   |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@login                  | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | logout                  |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@logout                 | web          |
|        | POST     | password/email          |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | password/reset          |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@reset              | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset/{token?} |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm      | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | profile                 |      | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@getProfile                  | web,web,auth |
|        | GET|HEAD | profile/edit            |      | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@editProfile                 | web,web,auth |
|        | GET|HEAD | register                |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm   | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | register                |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@register               | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | update_email            |      | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@updateEmail                 | web,web,auth |
|        | POST     | update_name             |      | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@updateName                  | web,web,auth |
|        | POST     | update_password         |      | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@updatePassword              | web,web,auth |
|        | POST     | update_profile_picture  |      | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@updateProfilePicture        | web,web,auth |
+--------+----------+-------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: you have sure that this path is correct ? public function updateName(Requests\UpdateNameRequest $request)

I think it should be only "UpdateNameRequest"

Comment: yes im sure it the correct path

Comment: i tried to run it the way you said to me and it gave me this error `Class App\Http\Controllers\UpdateNameRequest does not exist`

Comment: uh..ok.. i can't find any errors in there. As you said that the page is only refreshing, you can display all errors on your view to check if something else is barring your validation.

http://pastebin.com/igHK5bif

Comment: can you remove the `web` middleware and try again . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error variable is returning empty value. Thats why no errors is showing just seeming the page is being refreshed. Ur validation is working but error value is not showing.

Try it:
In app\Http\Kernel.php move `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` from the `web` `$middlewareGroups` to `$middleware`

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I changed the `middleware` in my `routes.php` file from `web` to `auth` and the validation works now.

Answer (score 10):

I just want to add Something for those who check the validation with postman or any other applications in this category, make sure you add

> Accept: application/json

to Header tab or you will not get application error and the page is just refreshed and return 200

Comment: yeah that was it for me

Comment: Thansk for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the Form Builder? Laravel Collective have made a guide on how to install the HTML & Form Facades. You can find it here: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html

Comment: yes i did. when i do view source from the browser the form looks fine

Comment: kindly check it again i added the form output

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what it is but here are a couple of things to try:

Explicitly add `method => post`

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'update_name', 'method' => 'post')) !!}
```

Check your routes to make sure the route is correctly registered. Run:

```
`php artisan route:list`
```

If all else fails try using [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) to manually send a POST request. This will at least let you identify whether the issue is in your form or in setting up the POST route.

Lastly, not related to this issue, I'd recommend keeping it simple. On a route like this there's not any need to have a Request class, just use inline validation.

```
public function updateName(Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required'
    ]);
    return dd($request->all());
}
```

Comment: i tried to run `http://localhost:8000/update_name` on postman and gave me a html page generated by laravel  with this error             `Whoops, looks like something went wrong. TokenMismatchException`

Comment: when i run this still nothing happens `public function updateName(Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required'
    ]);
    return dd($request->all());
}`

Comment: but when i do this `public function updateName(Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    return dd($request->all());
}` it works fine

Comment: i think the problem comes when i try to use rules to validate. do you have an idea on how to fix this? i already spent hours trying to get this working but i still cant do it right. ive done this before with my other projects and it works fine i just dont know why it doesnt work now. do you think its a bug in laravel?

Comment: @Marley If you think it's a validation error just put a dd() at the beginning of the method you're testing. When trouble shooting narrow it down to as far as you need to get something working and then build from there. Doubtful that it's a bug in Laravel.

Comment: I changed the `middleware` in my `routes.php` file from `web` to `auth` and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting TokenMismatchException .. make sure your session storage path is writable

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem I changed this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('profile/edit', 'UserController@editProfile');
    Route::post('update_name', 'UserController@updateName');
});
```

to:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('profile/edit', 'UserController@editProfile');
    Route::post('update_name', 'UserController@updateName');
});
```

Thank you guys :)

Answer (score -1):

You can also get this error if the number of fields you are validating is more than there is on the submitted form.

Make sure that you are not validating more fields that there is on the submitted form.